# Room query that returns List<Object> freezes application

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-room

I've tried using the below code to load some data from my database and display them in an activity:

```java
PhoneNumberViewModel phoneNumberViewModel =
        new ViewModelProvider(WorksideContactCard.this).get(PhoneNumberViewModel.class);

phoneNumberViewModel
    .getPhoneNumbersById(contactID)
    .observe(this,
             numbers -> {
                 phoneNumberList = numbers;
             });
```

To be precise, I needn't observe the data changing, as the data will be refreshed if the activity is resumed. But the above code freezes my application, although I am accessing the DB using an `AsyncTask` in my other class.

Why could this be so?

EDIT:

PhoneNumberViewModel.class:

```
public class PhoneNumberViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private PhoneNumberRepository phoneNumberRepository;
    private LiveData<List<PhoneNumber>> allPhoneNumbers;

    public PhoneNumberViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        phoneNumberRepository = new PhoneNumberRepository(application);
        allPhoneNumbers = phoneNumberRepository.getAllPhoneNumbersLive();
    }

    public void insert(PhoneNumber phoneNumber) {
        System.out.println("[PhoneNumberRepository] Adding new phoneNumber");
        phoneNumberRepository.insert(phoneNumber);
    }

    public void update(PhoneNumber phoneNumber) {
        phoneNumberRepository.update(phoneNumber);
    }

    public void delete(PhoneNumber phoneNumber) {
        phoneNumberRepository.delete(phoneNumber);
    }

    public LiveData<List<PhoneNumber>> getAllPhoneNumbers() {
        return allPhoneNumbers;
    }

    public LiveData<List<PhoneNumber>> getPhoneNumbersById(long contactId)
            throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        return phoneNumberRepository.getPhoneNumbersByContactId(contactId);
    }
```

PhoneNumberRepository.class

```
public class PhoneNumberRepository {
    private PhoneNumberDao phoneNumberDao;
    private LiveData<List<PhoneNumber>> allPhoneNumbers;
    private LiveData<List<PhoneNumber>> phoneNumbersByIdList;

    public PhoneNumberRepository(Application application) {

        WorksideDatabase database = WorksideDatabase.getInstance(application);
        phoneNumberDao = database.phoneNumberDao();
        allPhoneNumbers = phoneNumberDao.getAllPhoneNumbers();
    }

    ...

    public LiveData<List<PhoneNumber>> getAllPhoneNumbersLive() {
        return allPhoneNumbers;
    }

    public void deleteAllPhoneNumbers() {
        new DeleteAllPhoneNumbersAsyncTask(phoneNumberDao).execute();
    }

    public LiveData<List<PhoneNumber>> getPhoneNumbersByContactId(long id)
            throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        return new SelectPhoneNumberByIdAsyncTask(phoneNumberDao, id).get();
    }

    private static class SelectPhoneNumberByIdAsyncTask
            extends AsyncTask<Long, Void, LiveData<List<PhoneNumber>>> {

        private PhoneNumberDao phoneNumberDao;
        private Long ID;

        private SelectPhoneNumberByIdAsyncTask(PhoneNumberDao phoneNumberDao, Long contactId) {
            this.phoneNumberDao = phoneNumberDao;
            ID = contactId;
        }

        @Override
        protected LiveData<List<PhoneNumber>> doInBackground(Long... contactId) {

            ID = contactId[0];

            return phoneNumberDao.getPhoneNumbersById(ID);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

PhoneNumberDao.class:

```
@Dao
public interface PhoneNumberDao {

    @Insert
    void insert(PhoneNumber phoneNumber);

    @Update
    void update(PhoneNumber phoneNumber);

    @Delete
    void delete(PhoneNumber phoneNumber);

    // Probably uneeded method
    @Query("DELETE FROM phone_numbers_table")
    void deleteAllPhoneNumbers();

    // Delete entry/entries by ID
    @Query("DELETE FROM phone_numbers_table WHERE id = :phoneNumberId")
    void deleteByPhoneNumberId(long phoneNumberId);

    // Retrieve entry/entries by contact ID
    //    @Query("SELECT * FROM phone_numbers_table WHERE contact_id = :contactId")
    //    List<PhoneNumber> getPhoneNumbersById(long contactId);

    // Retrieve all saved phone numbers in LiveData format
    @Query("SELECT * FROM phone_numbers_table")
    LiveData<List<PhoneNumber>> getAllPhoneNumbers();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM phone_numbers_table WHERE contact_id = :contactId")
    LiveData<List<PhoneNumber>> getPhoneNumbersById(long contactId);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM phone_numbers_table")
    List<PhoneNumber> getAll();
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the database initialization and the Async Task too ...

Comment: @FaizanMir Hi, I've only just noticed that I'm not initializing the DB in this specific fragment, and not initializing a `PhoneNumberDao` object from it.Perhaps that is the source of my error?

Comment: That shouldnt be an issue if you are using a MVVM model and initializing the database in the repository, In any case if that was the issue the app would crash with a NullPointerException,You can add a lil bit more code to be precise

Comment: @FaizanMir relevant classes added in edited answer, let me know if you have any ideas on top of your head.

Comment: have you used allowMainThreadQueries() in your room initialization ?

Comment: return new SelectPhoneNumberByIdAsyncTask(phoneNumberDao, id).get(); this here is youtr problem ,.get() call blocks the main thread

Comment: I would suggest switching to Kotlin and using Coroutines or here you can handle this using callbacks and not using AsyncTask.get() which blocks the main thread

Comment: Ok thank you, will give it a try and hope it will work. If you'd like, you can add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @FaizanMir actually - does that method need to return a new SelectPhoneNumberByIdAsyncTask(phoneNumberDao, id).get() like so? Could I change getPhoneNumbersByContactId() to be void instead?, and still get the data I want?

Comment: Ok so there are a couple of ways to get the data from the async task 1) would be using an interface and 2) would be overloading the on postExecute in the async task. I personally prefer the first one..

Comment: you can do something like  an Interface in the Async task as OnPhoneNumberReturned{ void passDatatoAnyClass(LiveData<List<PhoneNumber> list)} ,make a reference of it as OnPhoneNumberReturned mListener and then implement the interface in the repository class and then finally do mListener.passDatatoAnyClass(LiveData<List<PhoneNumber> list) in the async doInBackground method,Dont forget to pass the reference of the interface to the async task

Comment: I have edited my answer, You might have to move the Async task out of the repositoty class inorder to remove the cyclic inheritance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return new SelectPhoneNumberByIdAsyncTask(phoneNumberDao, id).get();
```

this here is your problem ,.get() call blocks the main thread
I would suggest switching to Kotlin and using Coroutines or here you can handle this using callbacks and not using AsyncTask.get() which blocks the main thread.Also BTW Async Task is going to be deprecated last I heard ,So keep that in mind too.
This is one solution the problem

```
public class Repository implements 
SelectPhoneNumberByIdAsyncTask.OnPhoneNumberFound {


@Override
public void onPhoneNumberFound(LiveData<List<Object>> list) {
   //you can get the data you want here
}



} 


 class SelectPhoneNumberByIdAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Long, Void, 
  LiveData<List<PhoneNumber//Correct this>>> {

interface OnPhoneNumberFound{
    void onPhoneNumberFound(LiveData<List<PhoneNumberDao>> list);
}
OnPhoneNumberFound mListener;


private PhoneNumberDao phoneNumberDao;
private Long ID;

private SelectPhoneNumberByIdAsyncTask(Object phoneNumberDao, Long contactId) {
    this.phoneNumberDao = phoneNumberDao;
    ID = contactId;
}

@Override
protected LiveData<List<Object>> doInBackground(Long... contactId) {
    ID = contactId[0];
    mListener.onPhoneNumberFound(phoneNumberDao.getPhoneNumbersById(ID));
    return null;
}
```

}

use .execute() call now instead of .get()